# VBA Code Question: Can I make GoTo be something variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I was just wondering if I could have my macro skip to a label that is variable? So something like the below (which doesn't work). The idea would be to generate a code based on the time and skip to that label in my code. So if the code is 900, i'd like it to skip to 900: and set x=1.

I hope this is clear enough.

```
Sub test()

Dim skipcode As String

'generate the label name
    If Minute(Now) > 28 And Minute(Now) < 58 Then
        If Hour(Now) = 0 Then
           skipcode = "0030"
        Else
            skipcode = Hour(Now) & "30"
        End If
    Else
        If Hour(Now) = 0 Then
           skipcode = "000"
        Else
            skipcode = Hour(Now) & "00"
        End If
    End If

'attempting to get the macro to skip to the label
    GoTo skipcode


' desired skip point
900:
x = 1

1000:
x = 2

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this...

Comment: Just before `900:` line, add the following line: `skipcode:`. Saying that, @NickA question stands.. don't see why you would want to do that?

Comment: BTW: i think, your code can be simplified this way: `skipcode = IIf(Minute(dt)>28 And Minute(dt)<58, Hour(dt) & "30", Hour(dt) & "00")`

Comment: IMHO, you should avoid using GoTo, except for error handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim skipcode As String
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = Now
    'i'd simplify your set of `if` - this way:
    skipcode = IIf(Minute(dt)>28 And Minute(dt)<58, Hour(dt) & "30", Hour(dt) & "00")

    'attempting to get the macro to skip to the label
    GoTo SkipPoint


' desired skip point
SkipPoint: 

    Select Case skipcode 
        Case "900" 'needs double quotes due to type of variable
            x = 1
        Case "1000"
            x = 2
    End Select


End Sub
```

**[EDIT]**

Accordingly to @Zack suggestion, a finall version of your procedure might look like:

```
Sub test()

    Dim skipcode As String
    Dim dt As Date

    dt = Now
    skipcode = IIf(Minute(dt)>28 And Minute(dt)<58, Hour(dt) & "30", Hour(dt) & "00")

    Select Case skipcode 
        Case "900" 'needs double quotes due to type of variable
            x = 1
        Case "1000"
            x = 2
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You're very welcome. I'd suggest to convert `sub` into `function` and return `x` as a result ;) If my answer was helpful, please, accept it.

Comment: But then the obvious question is why don't you just remove the label and GoTo?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Select Case functionality which basically does what I need so can def get rid of theGoto and label

Comment: @Zack, Good point (+1), but it provides more control than set of subroutines. I've updated my answer due to your suggestion.

Comment: My comment was really less about your answer, and more about the question...a number of people have pointed out by this point that there seems to be no real need for a GOTO (not that they should always be considered harmful, but perhaps just unnecessary in this case). Good answer nonetheless. :)